# Question Concerning Plate Letter Ordering Probability

Tags: probability, combinations

Suppose that motorcar license plates consist of six random letters of the alphabet (excluding
I, O and Q so there are only 23 letters in use). How many motorcars should you own in order
to have a better than 90% chance that at least one of your license plates has two letters that
are the same next to each other?

I understand that the total number of plates allowed (assuming repetition of letters allowed) is $$23^{6} = 148,035,889 $$

I understand that a typical layout for a plate and having 2 of the same letters is as follows

ex:

AABBBB
BAABBB
BBAABB
BBBAAB
BBBBAA

And thus there are five combinations of double letters for each $$23^4$$ amount of letter combinations that follow thereafter.

So am I simply multiplying $$23^4 $$ by 23 and 5?

I also am very confused as to how I can arrive at the 90% probability

Comment: First: What is the probability that a randomly chosen plate does not have two same letters adjacent?

Comment: is that simply $$(22^2)*(23^4)$$?

Comment: No. We're looking for a probability, which will be expressed as a fraction. Find the probability that the second letter is not the same as the first, the third not the same as the second, and so on.

Comment: Ok so the probability I arrived at was $$ 23/23*22/23*22/23*22/23*22/23*22/23 = (23*22*22*22*22*22)/23^6 = 118533536/148035889 = 0.800708 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there are 15 plate layouts that have pairs next to each other, not 5.
AABBBB
BAABBB
BBAABB
BBBAAB
BBBBAA
AAABBB
BAAABB
BBAAAB
BBBAAA
AAAABB
BAAAAB
BBAAAA
AAAAAB
BAAAAA
AAAAAA
This doesn't actually matter for the problem though.

Probability that a plate has at least one pair of matching digits:
$$\frac{1}{23}+\frac{22}{23^2}+\frac{22^2}{23^3}+\frac{22^3}{23^4}+\frac{22^4}{23^5}\approx .20$$
This adds the probability that each of digits 1-5 is the first digit in a duplicate pair, forcing no duplicates before this.

Next use the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to find the amount of cars to own (n) for a greater than 90% chance, which is 1 minus the chance of owning no cars that qualify.
$$1 - {n \choose 0} .20^0 .80^n \ge .90$$
Solve for n.
$$ 1 - 1\times1\times.80^n \ge .90$$
$$.80^n \le .1$$
$$n=11$$